# Does The Wither have preferred targets?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to make a "custom" and special Wither cage. For that, I want to know: Of any of the passive mobs, which one would be most likely to be targeted by wither?

- Dog
- Snow Golem
- Iron Golem
- something else, like a villager

The cage shouldn't be closed, because I want to be able to keep the wither as focused on its target as possible.

Comment: Minecraft version? It might not matter but would help when testing.

Comment: The last one, 1.11 I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Withers prioritize Iron Golems over other mobs. I tested this by spawning a bunch of different mobs far apart from each other, then spawning a few Withers. All of them attacked the Iron Golems before heading towards other mobs.

[Video 1](https://youtu.be/zMqIWbnoYPQ): Do Withers attack mobs closest to them?

Result: Yes

[Video 2](https://youtu.be/0_fdqn9375g): Pigs VS Iron Golems

Result: Iron Golems > Pigs

[Video 3](https://youtu.be/7IGS-hWbmIQ): Wolves VS Iron Golems

Result:  Iron Golems > Wolves

[Video 4](https://youtu.be/fU8kuHxzCWY): Pigs VS Wolves

Result: Closest mob